# access local variable outside javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

How can I access my name variable inside outside.

```
function MyObject(){
        var name="Test"
    }

    var n=new MyObject();
    alert(n.name);
```

I want to alert this here.

Please guide me.

Comment: Add the `name` as property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating the instance of `MyObject` function, you need to add the `name` as it's property to access outside.

```js
function MyObject(){
    this.name="Test"
}

var n=new MyObject();
alert(n.name);
```

Comment: It isn't a global variable.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder This is not a global variable. It will be present inside the created object

Comment: correct... thanks for that.. can use var keyword and than i can access.. var name="Test"

Comment: @JavascriptCoder Once you used `var name = 'Test';` inside the function, it's scope is limited to that function. You can't access it outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make the name variable global by declaring without prefix var.

```
function MyObject(){
           name="Test";
        }

        var n=new MyObject();
        alert(name);
```

Comment: Why you need to create object for `MyObject` in this approach ? You can directly call the function right ?

Comment: Yes, we can. I have just copy paste the code and changed a little bit. I thought that MyObject might be used for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function person(first) {
    this.firstName = first;
}

var myFather = new person("John");
var myMother = new person("Sally");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"My father is " + myFather.firstName + ". My mother is " + myMother.firstName;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```